# Ich bin ES gewohnt oder ich bin gewohnt?

Tags: english-to-german, personal-pronoun

Ich bin gewohnt oder Ich bin **es** gewohnt? Ich verstehe nicht, warum es in diesem Satz steht.

Comment: You wouldn't just say "I'm used to" in English either, would you?

Comment: @DonHolgo Es ist üblich, Fragen in der Sprache zu beantworten / kommentieren, in der sie gestellt wurden (auch wenn "english-to-german" vllt. die Muttersprache andeutet).

Comment: Ich würde sagen: Kommt darauf an. Beide Konstruktionen sind möglich und üblich. "Ich bin gewohnt, dass …" klänge mit "es" sogar seltsam.

Comment: Könntest du bitte in der Frage den ganzen Satz zitieren? "Ich bin gewohnt" ist ja kein kompletter Satz. Ich vermute, es folgt noch ein ",dass ...."-Nebensatz oder ein "... zu ..."-Infinitiv?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Es" ist ein Platzhalter innerhalb des Satzes für das Akkusativ-Objekt. Das eigentliche Akkusativ-Objekt ist aber der "dass..."-Nebensatz oder "zu ..."-Infinitiv am Ende, der in der Frage nicht zitiert wurde.

In modernem Deutsch *kann* man für Objekte, die später als Nebensatz oder Infinitivkonstrukt folgen, so ein Platzhalter-Pronomen benutzen, aber es ist nicht nötig. Das kannst du dir frei aussuchen. Einen Unterschied in der Bedeutung gibt es praktisch nicht. Jeder hat Präferenzen, was für ihn oder sie besser klingt.

Ähnlich ist es beim Subjekt in

> Es gefällt mir, dass du immer gut zuhörst.
> Mir gefällt (es), dass du immer gut zuhörst.

oder mit dem Objekt in

> Ich mag es, dass er immer gut zuhört.
> Ich mag, dass er immer gut zuhört.

Also sind beide Varianten korrekt und eine Frage des Geschmacks:

> Ich bin gewohnt, dass mir niemand richtig zuhört. 
> Ich bin es gewohnt, dass mir niemand richtig zuhört.

Wenn man unbedingt einen Unterschied finden möchte: Die Variante mit "es" betont vielleicht etwas mehr die Aussage des Hauptsatzes, und die Variante ohne "es" stellt etwas mehr den Inhalt des Nebensatzes in den Vordergrund.

Comment: Vielen Dank! Jetzt verstehe ich.